# Can I create a website builder using Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I would like to create a service that allows users to design and develop 
web applications, similar to many of the drag-and-drop website builders (think ClickFunnels, Squarespace, Wix, etc.).

Is it possible, or better yet, wise to use Herkoku to manage these applications?

Each user could have multiple independent applications that would require its own webserver and database.

I know Heroku has a CLI, but is it possible for my service to execute a Heroku CLI Command *on behalf* of the customer?

For instance, if a user wants to create a new application, I would need to have an endpoint in my application which will execute the 'heroku create app' command, which would create an app for the user in my own Heroku account. Is this possible? Are there any examples of executing Heroku commands from within the application itself?

Any other major hurdles I'm missing?

Comment: Sure, you could use [the Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-api). It's gonna be inefficient to spin up dedicated dynos and databases for each tiny client, though. Wix, Squarespace, etc. don't do that.

Comment: Can applications share dynos? Would you then suggest that I package multiple clients together into one dyno?

Comment: Applications can't share dynos, but your "application" is the overall website builder. A signup form isn't a separate application from a landing page - they're just part of the website builder tool. As with Wix etc., you'd typically run all clients off one set of dynos that serve the right site with the right config/customizations based on the domain name.

Comment: But wouldn't each client require a separate heroku app in order to have a custom domain name? I guess I'm confused how a single set of dynos could serve www.client1website.com and www.client2website.com - I thought these needed to be treated as separate entities.

Comment: A single Heroku app can have up to 10,000 custom domains attached. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#rules-on-adding-domains

Comment: Ah I see. And then I would put logic in my overall application code to route a website visitor to the correct client application based on the domain name. Thanks!